# ExtendedRequestLibrary expected 2 non-keyword arguments, got 1

Tags: robotframework

I am getting an error as Keyword 'ExtendedRequestsLibrary.Get Request' expected 2 non-keyword arguments, got 1 with below code. is it because of   /ap?  the question mark. because when I just take endpoint as  /ap, it works.

```
Create Password OAuth2 Session    session     https://11.11.11.11:8081/token     clientid    clientsecret    username    password   scope   base_url=https://11.11.10.10:8080
 ${resp}=   ExtendedRequestsLibrary.Get Request     session      /ap?SD=20160510&P=WE&DV=31
```

Comment: did you try wrap up endpoint to string? Could you provide ExtendedRequestsLibrary.Get Request code?

Comment: Thanks V. Rob, wrapping endpoint to string worked